# installpath in OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: software-installation, openbsd

In the FAQ section of OpenBSD 5.5, it is recommended to use

```
export PKG_PATH=ftp://your.ftp.mirror/pub/OpenBSD/5.5/packages/`machine -a`/
```

and to add the above line to ~/.profile

Instead of doing the above, I appended the following line to pkg.conf as in the following:

```
echo installpath=ftp://your.ftp.mirror/pub/OpenBSD/$(uname -r)/packages/$(uname -m) | sudo tee /etc/pkg.conf
```

When I tried to download a package, there was an warning message stating: **wrong server 229**

What happened?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this... What do you mean by "download a package"? Something like `sudo pkg_add $MYPACKAGE`? No offense, just making sure: did you enter `your.ftp.mirror` literally or did you replace that by an appropriate address from the [official list](http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html#ftp) of ftp mirrors? Using `$(uname -r)` and `$(uname -m)` like that should be fine.

Comment: @damien: No offence taken. I am an OpenBSD beginner and you can tell by the type of questions I asked on this stackexchange. Exactly as you wrote, I typed `sudo pkg_add -i -v <packagename>`. The mirror is `ftp://ftp5.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/`

Comment: @damien: Can I ask you a related question? Is the following syntax correct? export PKG_PATH=ftp://ftp.mirror/pub/OpenBSD/5.5/packages/``machine -a``/:PKG_PATH=ftp://ftp.mirror/pub/OpenBSD/patches/5.5/common/

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Your first comment makes sense and this looks okay. Your second comment doesn't make that much sense to me. Your `PKG_PATH` should point to a colon separated list of *package directories*, `.../$(uname -r)/packages/$(uname -m)/` on your preferred mirrors, possibly via different protocols (ftp, http(s), scp). Choosing just one should usually be fine. *Patches* don't have anything to do with *packages*. The former are for security fixes to the *base system* (e.g. patching the heartbleed vuln), while the latter are for *your personal extensions* of the base system.

Comment: You have to apply patches *manually* to the source tree, then compile and install the relevant parts, as detailed in the first few lines of each one of the patches. Again, the `PKG_*` tools don't have anything to do with that. See [following stable](http://www.openbsd.org/stable.html) for detailed instructions on following the stable (=patch) branch.

Comment: Complementing @damien's answer, [m:tier](http://stable.mtier.org) distributes patched binaries in package format, e.g., `binpatch55-amd64-openssl-2.0` applies patches 002 and 004 (heartbleed and other fixes for OpenSSL) on `amd64` machines, so you can have `-stable` without having to compile stuff.

Comment: @ZéLoff: I've revisited m:tier's website many times and hesitated to use the binaries it's offering. The reason is m:tier might place backdoors and/or trojans in them.

Comment: @damien: In your first comment to my original post and I quote `did you replace that by an appropriate address from the official list of ftp mirrors?` how did you create a clickable link on the words `official list`? I've re-looked at the `mini-Markdown formatting tips` and search the `Help` section and still was unable to find the answer.

Comment: I used something like `[official list](http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html#ftp)` to get [official list](http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html#ftp).

Comment: @damien Thanks for your answer. Why is there a need to append `#ftp` to `ftp.html`?

Comment: @damien There's something I'd like to discuss with you in a chatroom. As my points are insufficient to invite you to a chat, could you invite me instead? And please let me know the date and time you're available. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing should be ok. I think the problem was on the remote end.  You used a URI with ftp so this is just a response code from the remote ftp server you were trying to pull packages from.

The return codes from ftp servers come as three digit numbers with the first and second digits acting as a sort of classification system.  The first digit (2) is telling you about the reponse which was in this case a "positive completion reply" meaning the server did what you asked it to do and it's ready to do something else.  The second digit (2) tells you this code is dealing with connection information.  The final third digit (9) completes the code and makes the error specific which in this case means the server went into extended passive mode.

In general, the reply code text varies from one server implementation to another so the 'wrong server' part probably came from someone configuring the ftp server to cough back that text.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that you can look up ftp error codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) on wikipedia (and a bunch of other places).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I feel I'm more educated already :)